# Изменить внутренний блок iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, iframe

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу добраться до внутренних данных iframe, через метод jquery.contents()не получается, я так понимаю потому что на момент срабатывания скрипта iframe не видно ещё. Он появляется на экране после клика по кнопке.

```
<div class="data_colapse-381" id="data_colapse" data-iframe- 
  381="<iframe src=\''.$row['link'].'\' 
    width=\'1000\'height=\'700\'></iframe>">
</div>
```

Comment: `<iframe onload="yourFunction(this)" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Если контент ифрейма с другого домена, то и не получится из-за [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).